fitsSystemWindows does not work as expected
I use the following layout
<ConstraintLayout>
 <CoordinatorLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </CoordinatorLayout>
 <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </FrameLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>

In ActivityMain t there is the function "WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)"
so that the image can overflow into the statusBar
When I want to add a fragment with the following layout
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

And my problem is that I want the ImageView to occupy the statusBar and the rest will not occupy, but "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" has no effect at all.
